# MySql count result from another table not return correct number

Tags: mysql, sql

In my query i want to count how much user have photos and how much have pets. When i count how much pets he have that work good. When i try to count how much photos have than not work. He return me wrong result.

**Full query is :**

```
  SELECT  

acc.account_id,
CONCAT(acc.account_firstname,' ', acc.account_lastname) AS full_name, 
acc.account_username AS username,
acc.account_website_url AS website,
g.gender_name AS gender,
acc.account_birthday AS birthday,
acc_t.account_type_name AS account_group,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pb_account_photos WHERE owner_id = acc.account_id) AS photoCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pb_account_photo_albums WHERE album_account_id = acc.account_id) AS photoAlbumCount,
CONCAT(country.country_name,'/',city.city_name) AS location,
COUNT(p.pet_id) AS petCount,
(SELECT CONCAT(s.value, '/uploads/user_data/',acc.account_id,'/photos/',photo.photo_guid, '/',.photo.photo_name) FROM pb_settings AS s WHERE s.key = 'siteurl') AS profile_picture,
(SELECT CONCAT(s.value, '/uploads/user_data/',acc.account_id,'/photos/',cover.photo_guid, '/',.cover.photo_name) FROM pb_settings AS s WHERE s.key = 'siteurl') AS cover_picture

FROM pb_accounts AS acc

LEFT JOIN pb_account_genders AS g ON g.gender_id = acc.account_gender_id
LEFT JOIN pb_animal_pets AS p ON p.pet_owner_id = acc.account_id
LEFT JOIN pb_account_types AS acc_t ON acc_t.account_type_id = acc.account_type_id
LEFT JOIN pb_locations AS loc ON loc.location_id = acc.account_location_id
LEFT JOIN pb_country AS country ON country.country_id = loc.location_id
LEFT JOIN pb_city AS city ON city.city_id = loc.city_id
LEFT JOIN pb_account_photos AS photo ON photo.photo_id = acc.profile_picture_id
LEFT JOIN pb_account_photos AS cover ON cover.photo_id = acc.profile_cover_picture_id

WHERE acc.account_id = 1 GROUP BY acc.account_id
```

**Output**

```
account_id  full_name         username  website         gender  birthday    account_group  photoCount  location        petCount  profile_picture                                                                                                              cover_picture                                                                                                                
----------  ----------------  --------  --------------  ------  ----------  -------------  ----------  --------------  --------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     1    Jon Doe    jondoe013     www.google.com    Male   2016-01-07  Administrator               2  Serbia/Belgrade         2  http://work.example.com/uploads/user_data/1/photos/9A5EF85E-F691-F42E-C20C-BCDC765BFA1B/6c28b264470e7a7f2829ea5b7290cbba.jpg  http://work.example.com/uploads/user_data/1/photos/14B6D588-68E6-6783-324B-673CBCCD4FBC/6db0935929d08f7c51ded014bd9e73df.jpg
```

**Problem:**
Query return `photoCount` just 2 but i have 123 pictures. I also try to `Group by` for photo_id but not working.

Also in this case i use subquery and also try to remove subquery for `photoCount` and put `COUNT(photo.*) AS photoCount` and result is the same

Comment: Is it just me, or you're counting the pet table for the `photocount` ?

Comment: ups i paste old query\

Comment: When you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pb_account_photos WHERE owner_id = 1` , what do you get as output ?

Comment: Like i say  i get `123`